# Magento 2.1 redirects in Observer after payment

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, payment-methods, redirect, redirection

I'm creating a payment method gateway, that requires after place order in the frontend, redirects to the custom controller that I've created.

I created an observer **sales_order_payment_place_end** to catch payment order and redirect to my controller, but this doesn't work and redirect to **success page**.

[image]

[image]

**Edit**:

I'm trying to build a payment gateway like PayPal (place order and redirect to its page, login and pay, and finally redirect to store to sucess page)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `sales_order_payment_place_end` event for redirection.
I donot thin you have build the payment module properly,please follow

https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway
 or

Follow the article https://www.classyllama.com/blog/how-to-create-payment-method-magento-2